# Ignoring trailing and leading newlines when splitting by \n?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I'm trying to split some text into individual lines while preserving whitespace for a JS syntax highlighter:

```
var text = '\n\n\ntest\n\ntext\n\n';
```

When I use `.split('\n')`, I get a bunch of blank elements in my array:

```
> text.split('\n');
["", "", "", "test", "", "text", "", ""]
```

Currently, I `.strip()` the text before splitting it, but that looks messy:

```
> text.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').split('\n');
["test", "", "text"]
```

Is there any way to disregard trailing and leading newlines when using `.split()`? I tried writing a regex, but that didn't go so well.

Comment: split() is quite a simple one-purpose function (which I think is good) and even though regexp gives it a huge flexibility, it has its limits, so in my opinion using replace() (which is a common replacement for missing trim() in this form) is perfectly fine. If you find it "messy", you can always make it more readable by extracting parts of it to separate functions (like trim(), which is quite reusable too).

Answer (score 2):

```
var text = '\n\n\ntest\n\ntext\n\n lorem ipsum';
var arr = text.match(/[ \w]+/g);

console.log(arr); //=> ["test", "text", " lorem ipsum"]
```

Comment: I'm trying to preserve the whitespace that appears within the text itself as well.

Comment: @Blender: See edit, that should work. Also what are you trying to do exactly? Just get all lines separately into an array?

Comment: I'm also trying to preserve newlines within the text (it's for a JS syntax highlighter), which I don't think is possible with just one sane regex. `.trim().split('\n')` is about as clean as it gets. Thanks  for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `split(/\n+/)` to consume as many newlines as possible and then split.

Comment: I'm trying to preserve the whitespace that appears within the text itself as well.

Answer (score 0):

Though I can't get your logic entirely, maybe the following helps you to do the parsing using `split`:

```
var text = "\n\n\ntest\n\ntext\n\n",
    parsed = ("\n" + text + "\n").split(/^\n+|\n+$|\n/).slice(1, -1);

console.log(parsed);   // ["test", "", "text"]
```

Comment: it should be probably more like (" " + text + " ").split(/^\s+|\s+$|\n/).slice(1, -1), but even then it does not seem a big improvement over the replace/trim approach :)